# Find all entire functions such that $ | f'(z) | \leq 1 $ for all $z$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Using the extended version of Liouvilles Theorem, can we conclude that $ | f(z) | \leq z$? In other words, $f(z) $ must be a constant function?

Comment: What about $f(z) = 17 + z/2$?

Comment: Is entire and fulfills my inequality, so my conclusion is wrong.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative of an entire function is entire, so I am not sure what extension you need here.

Comment: Yes, how can we summerize all entire functions such that $ | f' | \leq 1 $?

Comment: @Oskar Your question is answered, just think about it.

Comment: I get it now, thanks! The question was way more simple than I thought, I kinda overthinked it..